# How do I find a specific string in a list of strings with similar values

Tags: java, arrays

In a list of strings, the individual strings have a bunch of numbers separated by commas.

ex.

```
List<String> numberGroups = {"55,46,10,0,85,80,67","100,64,70,6","1,23,59,60","5,0,98,54"};
```

I want to identify numberGroups that only have a single "0".. but my code is finding any "0" and returning all the groups since the others contain a 0 in "100", "70".. etc. I only want to find strings with a single 0 and add that string to a list to return.

Here is what I have -

```
public static List<String> findGroups(List<String> groups){
        List<String> grp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String x : groups) {
            if(x.contains("0")) {
                grp.add(x);
            }
        }
        return grp;
    }
``
```

Comment: contains(",0,") replace contains("0")

Comment: @FLYFLU I knew it was going to be something simple. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Java you are using but if it is at least version 8 you can do the following.

```
public static List<String> findGroups(List<String> groups){
        List<String> grp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String x : groups) {
            long count = x.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'e').count();
            if( count < 2 ) {
                grp.add(x);
            }
        }
        return grp;
    }
```

Comment: I assume you meant `== '0'`? --- I think that's a misinterpretation of the question, though I can see how it could be read like that. I believe OP means that the string must contain the *number* `0`, i.e. the number is a single "0", not that it must contain the *digit* `0` only once. E.g. the first string should match, because it has a `0` number (the `0` digit in `80` has no impact), but the second string should not match, since the only `0` digits are part of bigger numbers (`100` and `70`).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with some nested streams, where each number group is split by their separator to test each of its number for a match and then deciding to keep based on the number of matches:

```
 var numberGroupsWithOneZero = 
      numberGroups.stream()
                  .filter(numberGroup -> {
                      long zeroCount = 
                          Stream.of(numberGroup.split(","))
                                .filter(number -> number.equals("0"))
                                .count();
                      return zeroCount == 1;
                   })
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Given the list `["55,46,10,0,85,80,67","100,64,70,6","1,23,59,60","5,0,98,54"]` it produces `["55,46,10,0,85,80,67", "5,0,98,54"]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `0` can be first (`0,...`), last (`...,0`), in the middle (`...,0,...`), or standalone (`0`).

Easiest way to check all that is with a regex looking for one or more zeros (`0`, `00`, ...), that is at beginning or preceded by comma, or is at end or followed by comma.

Like this: `(^|,)0+(,|$)`

Since we don't actually need to capture anything, we'll change that to use non-capturing groups.

```java
public static List<String> findGroups(List<String> groups){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|,)0+(?:,|$)");
    List<String> grp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : groups) {
        if (p.matcher(s).find()) {
            grp.add(x);
        }
    }
    return grp;
}
```